# Error 1241 - Copiar columnas con datos de una tabla a otra en una misma Base De Datos

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos

estoy intentando copiar los datos de algunas columnas de una tabla a otra, las tablas se realizaron con el mismo script, tienen las mismas columnas y las mismas indicaciones. Pero al ejecutar el código me arroja el error 1241 "Operando debe tener 1 columna(s)", adjunto el código para recibir alguna ayuda, ya que esto es solo copiar y pegar, mi tabla de destino está totalmente vacía

```
`INSERT INTO producto_detalle
(
    id,
    producto_id,
    precio_compra,
    precio_venta,
    iva,
    ultima_compra,
    proveedor_id,
    descuento,
    stock_ideal,
    stock_maximo,
    stock_id,
    consumo_promedio,
    multiplo_compra,
    mercaderia,
    sucursal_id,
    activo,
    created_at,
    updated_at,
    stock
)
SELECT 
(
  p2.id,
  p2.producto_id,
  p2.precio_compra,
  p2.precio_venta,
  p2.iva,
  p2.ultima_compra,
  p2.proveedor_id,
  p2.descuento,
  p2.stock_ideal,
  p2.stock_maximo,
  p2.stock_id,
  p2.consumo_promedio,
p2.multiplo_compra,
  p2.mercaderia,
  p2.sucursal_id,
  p2.activo,
p2.created_at,
  p2.updated_at,
  p2.stock
)
FROM  producto_detalle_antiguo p2;`
```

Comment: Sacale los parentesis al select

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tienes un error de sintaxis, tienes que remover los paréntesis `()` de tu sentencia `SELECT`

```
INSERT INTO producto_detalle
(
    id,
    producto_id,
    precio_compra,
    precio_venta,
    iva,
    ultima_compra,
    proveedor_id,
    descuento,
    stock_ideal,
    stock_maximo,
    stock_id,
    consumo_promedio,
    multiplo_compra,
    mercaderia,
    sucursal_id,
    activo,
    created_at,
    updated_at,
    stock
)
SELECT 

  p2.id,
  p2.producto_id,
  p2.precio_compra,
  p2.precio_venta,
  p2.iva,
  p2.ultima_compra,
  p2.proveedor_id,
  p2.descuento,
  p2.stock_ideal,
  p2.stock_maximo,
  p2.stock_id,
  p2.consumo_promedio,
  p2.multiplo_compra,
  p2.mercaderia,
  p2.sucursal_id,
  p2.activo,
  p2.created_at,
  p2.updated_at,
  p2.stock

FROM  producto_detalle_antiguo p2;
```

---

O simplemente podrías realizar lo siguiente, para no especificar cada una de las columnas que tiene la tabla:

```
INSERT INTO producto_detalle SELECT * FROM  producto_detalle_antiguo;
```

---

Aquí tienes un [enlace](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert_into_select.asp) con información (en inglés) referente a la inserción de datos, con una sentencia `SELECT` en **MySQL**

Comment: Muchas gracias, los paréntesis eran el error, gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Creando la tabla:

```
CREATE TABLE producto_detalle
 AS SELECT * FROM producto_detalle_antiguo;
```

Insertando en tabla:

```
INSERT INTO producto_detalle SELECT * FROM producto_detalle_antiguo;
```